# Solving linear systems by fft

Tags: linear-solver, fourier-analysis

I read in a paper and also at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#In_linear_equations) that we can solve the system 
$$Ax=B$$
by Fast Fourier Transform, where $A$ is a circulant matrix. The solution is
$$x=\mathtt{ifft}(\mathtt{fft}(B)/\mathtt{fft}(a))$$
where $a$ is first column of $A$, `ifft` is the inverse of `fft` and $/$ denotes component-wise division. For example, the solution of the following system
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ -4\\ 7\\ -6 \end{pmatrix}$$
is
$$x=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ -1\\ 2\\ -4 \end{pmatrix}$$
But when I implement $$x=\mathtt{ifft}(\mathtt{fft}(B)/\mathtt{fft}(a))$$, I get

$$x=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{118}{33}\\ - \frac{26}{33}\\ - \frac{53}{33}\\ \frac{142}{33}\\ - \frac{170}{33} \end{pmatrix}$$

What is my fault?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Can you please elaborate how to embed a matrix A into a circulant matrix. How would I zero pad the example above? How is the right hand side (vector B) padded? Thank you
Erik

Comment: I don't think you can use FFTs to solve a Toeplitz system rigourously. If it were possible, I don't see why there would be any need for the [Levinson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion), which was expressly developed for solving Toeplitz systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your matrix $A$ isn't a circulant matrix- it's just Toeplitz.  The method that you're trying to use fundamentally only works for circulant systems.

Furthermore, your $a$ vector doesn't have the "-1" in it anywhere, so you clearly don't have sufficient information.

A method that involves embedding the $n$ by $n$ Toeplitz matrix in a double-sized circulant matrix and doing an FFT on a vector of length $2n$ is described in

R. Kumar.  A Fast Algorithm for Solving a Toeplitz System of Equations. *IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing* 33(1): 1985. https://doi.org/10.1109/TASSP.1985.1164492

Comment: Thank you Mr. Borchers. I misunderstood some concepts, you corrected them.

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer? As Circulant Matrix is rectangular it means you need to extend $ \boldsymbol{x} $ as well.

Comment: Methods for solving circulant linear systems are discussed in On the Solution of Circulant Linear Systems by Mingkui Chen https://doi.org/10.1137/0724044